# AEM Sightly listening for when a component is added to a template

Tags: javascript, aem, sightly

How do you listen for events in Sightly? I have a wrapper component that holds information about its children, I want to be able to have the children react based on those changes. Think of the column component.

I just started looking at colctrl.js

/libs/wcm/foundation/components/parsys/colctrl/colctrl.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sightly is a templating language any business logic should be implemented in Java or server JavaScript files, not sure what you are trying to accomplish, maybe at rendering time your child page should look at its parent and see if something changed and react? Not sure if this will help you, maybe be more specific?

Comment: Thanks @Bambara, I ended up using cq:listeners in order to refresh as needed. It is not optimal but it does get the job done. After looking at Column control in more detail I realize that is how it is done with that component. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RefreshPageWhenModifyDialog.html

Comment: cq:listeners are the way to go if you only want a page refresh, enjoy! :-)